# How to model the ratio of count data between two treatments in R

Tags: r, proportion, ratio

I have count data (Detections), two treatments (Control and N) and a continuous variable (Amplitude)

```
Treatment  Detections   Amplitude  Proportion
Control        40            20          -
N              44            20          1.1
Control        40            40          -
N              20            40          .5
Control        40            60          -
N              10            60          .25
```

I initially wanted to model the proportion of N/Control detections with the increasing Amplitude variable (the Proportion variable in the table) as the trend in the data is with increasing amplitude, the proportion decreases. However modeling proportion data with betareg or gamlss (family BEINF) does not allow for proportions over 1 (obviously). I now realize that I actually am interested in modeling the ratio between the detections of the two treatments, because I do no want to throw out or manipulate data where the proportion would be over 1.

I have tried to recategorize the data as Success and Failure data so I could use binomial regression, but my predictions did not reflect my data at all. I was wondering if there was a way to model this type of ratio data in R, or if there is some way to transform my data so that I could model what I am interested in.

I want to show the trend in the data which is that as the Amplitude increases, the ratio of Detections between N:Control decreases (ie. there are more Control detections than N detections.

I realize I might be explaining things vaguely, if so I would be happy to clarify.

Comment: So in the end you want to model Proportion vs. Amplitude?  How would you feel about gamma regression?  But various forms of nonparametric or OLS regression might work just as well.

Comment: I want to essentially model Proportion vs Amplitude, but I want to take into account that the "Proportion" can be above 1 (ie. 1.5 or 4.2), so instead it is more of a ratio than a proportion. I don't know much about gamma regression but I'll look into it.

Comment: You have gotten solid advice as a comment to the duplicate. Don't model the ratio if you can model the counts.